# Apache + Passenger + Rails not serving assets after adding SSL certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ssl, asset-pipeline, production-environment

My Rails server has been working fine until adding an SSL certificate and using force_ssl, to the point where it will neither fully validate (says the site is only partially encrypted), nor load any assets.  All that loads is a static html page - with working links, but that's just about it.

Has anyone ever run into this problem before?

**UPDATE**

This is the stack trace I've been getting in production.log (there are several, this is just an example of one for a single request)

```
Started GET "/internal-nginx-static-locationassets/slide2.png" for 129.21.79.202 at 2012-07-24 10:18:39 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/internal-nginx-static-locationassets/slide2.png"):
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:321:in `start_request_handler'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:470:in `safe_fork'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:270:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rails_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `block in spawn_rails_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
  <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```